# Which pitfalls are there when using `IntStream.generate` with a stateful `IntSupplier`?

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose I want to use a Java 8 Stream with Fibonacci numbers. The nearest thing that Java offers to accomplish this is `IntStream.iterate` however this requires that I calculate the next Fibonacci only based on the previous number, but I need two previous numbers. To memorize the two previous generated numbers I could tackle the problem with `IntStream.generate` and a stateful `IntSupplier` like this:

```java
class FibonacciDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.generate(new FibonacciGenerator()).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
class FibonacciGenerator implements IntSupplier {
    private int previous = 0;
    private int previousPrevious = 1;

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        final int next = previous + previousPrevious;
        previousPrevious = previous;
        previous = next;
        return next;
    }
}
```

This works, but to my surprise I could not find anything in the manual whether this is a bad thing and should not be done or what problems could arise. So I did a little bit of source code reading and figured that when the generator will be used in a paralell stream the generator will be shared across multiple Spliterators. **So I guess I should make the method `getAsInt` `synchronized` so make it safe for parallel streams. Correct? Any more pitfalls?**

The above code is only an example of what  a stateful `IntSupplier` could be useful for in the first place but which is still simple enough so that everyone sees what is going on. The question is generally about stateful `IntSupplier` in conjunction with `IntStream.generate` and not directly about Fibonacci. (Although if there is a better way to get the job above done without a stateful `IntSupplier` that may of course be of interest.)

Comment: If you think you may have a bug, before writing any other code, you should write the test that exploits the bug.

Comment: The use of the forEach breaks and defeats the purporse of using parallel streams in the first place. The whole implementation of a fibonacci sequence must be a synchronized process since the following element depends on the sum of the previous two. Could you explain a bit further why would you be concerned about parallel streams in this case?

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha: First of all the above application prints 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55 which is exactly what Wikipedia says that the sequence should be and I don't quite get what you mean with "[it] is not doing fibonacci correctly if you look into it even befor running it".

Secondly I choose the example with forEach because it is simple and showcases why I'd like to write a stateful `IntSupplier` in the first place. The question is only about making `IntStream.generate(new FibonacciGenerator())` safe no matter what follows in the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, though it's not specified explicitly, the `generate()` method is designed to work with a stateless supplier. Stateful supplier will work correctly with sequential stream only. In parallel case you cannot fix the supplier just by adding `synchronized`. Let's simplify your problem and test the generator of sequential numbers. First, without synchronized:

```
public class IncrementDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.generate(new IncrementGenerator()).parallel()
                 .limit(200).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    }
}
class IncrementGenerator implements IntSupplier {
    private int previous = 0;

    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        return previous++;
    }
}
```

This code typically prints something like this:

```
1
4
7
9
11
31
35
...
373
376
379
0
3
5
7
9
10
...
214
217
220
222
```

So we have just some garbage. Some numbers are even repeating. Let's make `getAsInt` method `synchronized`:

```
0
3
6
9
12
15
...
221
223
226
1
4
7
10
13
...
356
359
362
```

Now numbers never repeat, but still the results are quite useless. The order is not fixed (even though we are used `forEachOrdered`). It does not even produce *first* 200 non-negative numbers, it just produces *some* non-repeating non-negative numbers. The same would be with your Fibonacci generator. Adding synchronized will guarantee you to have some non-repeating Fibonacci numbers (note however that `int` will quickly overflow for Fibonacci), but it will not be guaranteed which numbers will you see.

To generate consecutive Fibonacci numbers you can use `Stream.iterate` encapsulating the state in the intermediate container, then mapping this container to the resulting number like this:

```
Stream.iterate(new int[] {0, 1}, pair -> new int[] {pair[1], pair[0]+pair[1]})
    .mapToInt(pair -> pair[1])
    .parallel()
    .limit(200)
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Such code produces consecutive Fibonacci numbers even for parallel stream. Though parallelism will unlikely to improve speed here, at least it works correctly (it may improve the speed if you add some expensive operation into the pipeline).

Comment: I don't necessarily care for the order but that even the set does not match is good to know. I wonder what the whole `iterate` method is good for. The only thing I can think of is `Math.random`.

Comment: @yankee: since `java.util.Random` and its subclasses have their own, potentially more efficient stream creation methods, even `IntStream.generate(Math::random)` is not a recommended use case. In case of reference streams, `Stream.generate(MyClass::new)` might point into the direction of intended use cases…

Comment: Might still be worth mentioning that, performance aside, `DoubleStream.generate(Math::random)` is an example of a valid stream creation with a stateful supplier. The important point is that the created stream is *unordered*, so your code must not rely on the ordering to be a correct solution…